When to include possessive forms in checklists
https://www.osha.gov/etools/computer-workstations/checklists/evaluation

The monitor has sufficient adjustability so the top of the screen is at or below eye level so the user can read it without bending their head or neck down/back.

Monitor position is directly in front of the user so they do not have to twist head or neck.


I'm trying to write technical checklists by referring OSHA and I wonder why they sometimes omit their, its, etc. from their checklists and sometimes not. As you can see in the page I shared, I think some of the sentences actually have all the possessive forms. Why?

This dropping of the article with generic body parts (or parts of an assembly) occurs most often when a pair of  parts is presented.  "So that they do not have to twist head" would be unusual.

It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include a determiner in the cited context, but if one is included, their and the are both perfectly valid.

Compare I commit body and soul to... and I commit my body and soul to...

But not "I commit body to ..."  unless "soul" is mentioned later.

@TimR: Absolutely! I thought I'd upvoted you comment re that specific observation, but I see I neglected to do so.

...but note they locked arms / horns and they locked their horns.

I’m voting to close this because it is apparently a repeat of your own question of four days ago.

This question is similar to: omitting articles in checklists. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Bullet-pointed or numbered lists tend to appear in technical or instructional material. As such, they fall somewhere between formal and informal. There is a degree of formality because instructions have to be clear and so choice of language is important, but they don't necessarily adhere to rules of grammar related to things like sentence structure, for example. So, there is some flexibility, but here's some common guidelines.
If a checklist is preceded a 'lead-in' sentence then you can include something like an article or a pronoun in that to avoid repeating it in the list.
Notice the difference in these two examples:

Don't forget to bring:

a jacket
an umbrella
your ID



Don't forget to bring your

jacket
umbrella
ID


Your example is a bit different. It is a list of statements, and the proforma invites you to answer yes or no to denote that the statement is true or not. As such, they are all worded differently and there is no 'lead-in'. The language used in each item must make sense on its own, and clearly the writer has opted for an abbreviated, informal style of writing. The only rule when it comes to stylistic choices is consistency, and they appear to have used the same style throughout. One possible reason for this language is that, as it appears to be a health and safety evaluation, it could be used for any person, and using gender-neutral language (ie it does not say "his head and neck..") prevents it from not sounding inapplicable to anyone being assessed.

Thank you for answering. So you mean because these kinds of instructions are not formal, including his/her/their depends on the writer and there is no right or wrong? How about "the" of "(the) top of (the) screen"? I think these are necessary.
